# Osgi - Virgo 3.6 - Loading application Context

Tags: java, osgi, eclipse-virgo, blueprint-osgi

- Step 1 Root Bundle

I am creating a Jar Bundle deployed in Virgo Server 3.6, The Jar Works fine,

```
      <service ref="pluginManager" interface="com.roshka.osgi.manager.PluginManager" />
```

- Step 2 Plugin Jar Bundle

Then to test my first Bundle i am creating another Jar Bundle, that is a plugin JAR Bundle. And the the Bundle Plugin works fine, and call the first jar with successfully

- Step 3 Web Plugin Jar Bundle

To end, i want create a war bundle to consumes the First Jar Bundle, after read the documentation i am add to web.xml, i use a MVC Spring, works fine but can not inject the osgi bean service to call methods of first jar bundle

```
                <context-param>
                    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
                        <paramvalue>
                              org.eclipse.virgo.web.dm.ServerOsgiBundleXmlWebApplicationContext
                        </param-value>
                </context-param>

          <listener>
        <listener-class>
                  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
                </listener-class>


And create a applicationContext.xml to load a service


        <reference id="pluginManager" interface="com.roshka.osgi.manager.PluginManager" />
```

I think that, the problem is that the applicationContext.xml has not loaded, and my question what is the wrong in the war project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to specify your applicationContext.xml like this:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

in your web.xml?